# Radio Station not bringing dwellers?

Tags: fallout-shelter, android

My vault recently hit 20 dwellers so I built a radio studio, assigned my 2 dwellers with the highest charisma to it and gave them clothing with charisma buff. After 1 day with the studio and no new dwellers I spent 1,500 caps to upgrade it to the radio station, and 2 days later still no dwellers. I know the station has only a percentage chance to find a new dweller, but after this long with high charisma dwellers running it and the upgrade I thought it would have found at least one dweller by now. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just a really low chance of finding a dweller?

Thanks

Comment: The chance is really low.  When you said "High Charisma", are you talking about Charisma 10 with +5/+7 CHA equip or "High" as in more than 3?

Comment: The dwellers have 6 and 7 charisma and both have +3 clothing. That should be high enough right?

Comment: It takes a while.  With two dwellers at 10 CHA in a level 3 radio room and using +5 CHA outfits, I average 1 dweller every 12 hours.  If you need dwellers, getting some "action" is by far the best way.

Comment: Yes that would be ideal, but I'm only early game right now

Comment: You can get dwellers to have babies much earlier than getting the radio room.

Comment: I'm already making babies, I meant I'm to early game for charisma 10 dwellers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31785/discussion-between-nelson-and-baibro).

Answer (score 1):

Radio rooms have a very low chance of attracting new citizens to your vault. This is offset by the fact that the citizens the radio room attracts are already adults who wouldn't consume resources without providing a benefit in the same way a child born in the vault would.

Even when having radio hosts with charisma in the 8-10 range it will still take about half a day (or more) for more wastelanders to come to your vault. It is possible for them to arrive in groups of two or three, which is a boon.

The fact that you have not seen any new dwellers after two days while using radio hosts with high charisma and and upgraded radio room means that you are either have encountered a bug and the radio room is not working as intended or your vault is at maximum capacity and new vault dwellers cannot be added. I believe this is more likely to be a glitch because when at maximum vault capacity new wastelanders will queue at the entrance to the vault but will be unable to enter - rather than never appear at all. Consider destroying and rebuilding the radio room to fix the glitch or find alternate means to increase your population.